# Strange issue causing JS errors in Structure in EE Control Panel

Tags: ee2, structure

Very weird issue this - never seen it before. When I access Structure in the control panel I'm getting javascript errors because something is cutting off the end of the Structure js files that the CP is accessing via the following type of URLS:

`/admin.php?S=0&D=cp&C=javascript&M=load&package=structure&file=structure-collapse`

Basically the end of the JS file is being shown as:

`})(jQuery`

rather than:

`})(jQuery);`

which is what the actual file has. So it isn't an issue with the Structure files not having been uploaded properly.

[image]

I've even tried reinstalling on another server, but same issue. I've also upgraded EE to the latest 2.10.3 version and installed the most up to date Structure version (3.3.19). Same issue.

I'm running on Ubuntu 14.4 with Nginx and PHP-FPM.

Anybody any ideas?

**Update:** 
I've been able to fix this... in the weirdest way. By adding a couple of line breaks at the end of the following Structure javascript files:

- jquery.ui.nestedsortable.js
- structure-collapse.js

That's it!

Comment: What is your Structure module version ? Also, can you elaborate your question by adding JQuery console error screenshot ?

Comment: @Mufi  - thanks for the feedback. Added those details

Comment: Thanks for desc. I have an older version 3.3.10 that is running properly in `EE 2.10.x.` I think the version you are using is Buggy. Please try to upgrade or downgrade the module and give it a try

Comment: @Mufi But what I'm worried about is that it's the EE call to show the Structure js that is failing. The Structure version that I'm testing on today is 3.3.14.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to update to version 4.1.1 Theirs been a lot of bug fixes and stability enhancements in that version.  3.3.19 is currency 16 releases behind.

Comment: @TomJaeger This is EE2 - I thought 3.3.19 was the latest for EE2 (http://buildwithstructure.com/changelog)

Comment: @JimPannell Ah, just updated the changelog to add a message pointing to EEHarbor.com  (Thanks for bringing that to our attention!)  4.x supports both EE 2.x and 3.x in a unified code base.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to fix this... in the weirdest way. By adding a couple of line breaks at the end of the following Structure javascript files:

- jquery.ui.nestedsortable.js
- structure-collapse.js